# Can a Arduino Uno handle all these components?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, button, buzzer

Its my first project with an Arduino, so please bear with the dumb questions.

For this project of mine, I need an Ultrasonic Sensor, a Gyroscope, a Buzzer, three push buttons and an 16x2 LCD.

Can I connect all these components at once to an Arduino Uno? I mean will I run out of pins or not? Should I go for a Mega 2560 (will have to buy one though).

Edit: a GSM sim800 as well lol

Comment: ultrasonic s. 2 pins, buzzer 1 pin, buttons 3 pins, gyroscope i2c? 2 pins, LCD i2c? same two pins, not i2c LCD  6 pins. Uno has 13 pins.

Comment: Yeah getting I2C for LCD, but I don' think the gyro comes with one. Here's the link to it: [gyro](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B008BOPN40/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1)

Comment: The gyro is I2C too

Answer (score 1):

I think you're fine depends on the gyroscope model and lcd. 
-For ultrasonic sensor thats 2 pins 
-the lcd needs at least 6pins but with an i2c adapter you only need 2 pins
-3 push buttons 3 pins
-one pin for the buzzer 
Plenty of room left on the uno

Comment: Thanks for replying. So if I get a i2c, I'll be good to go? Here are the links to the components: [Gyro](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B008BOPN40/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1) [Ultrasonic](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00MYYE6XM/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1) [I2C](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B077TNW7M5/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1)  [Buzzer](https://www.amazon.in/Think-Bots-Piezoelectric-Active-Electronics-Projects/dp/B07552XRS2/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=buzzer&qid=1558859704&s=gateway&sr=8-2)